# How to create dynamic table in postgresql with django

Tags: python, django, postgresql, csv

My task is to upload a `.csv` file and dump the data in a postgresql database using django.

How can I create a table dynamically in postgresql using django to dump the `.csv` data into the database?

I have searched and found examples where we have to give attribute names while creating table but in my case I would not know the attribute names of the uploaded `.csv` beforehand.

How should I do the above?
I will be thankful if anyone can share some related links.

Comment: what's schemaless table?..

Comment: I think it's ordinary CSV data with variable header line. This rules out all simple import option, because to import a CSV you have to create a table with column names and types. It's impossible to determine the correct types from a csv file without additional information.

Comment: @VaoTsun i mean is there any way of creating table in django dynamically  without defining column names and types as user will be uploading different csvs with different attributes

Comment: @VaoTsun i mean is there any way of creating table in django dynamically  without defining column names and types as user will be uploading different csvs with different attributes

Comment: Are you forced to use Postgresql? You can't create models dynamically in django, you'd have to do that yourself.

Comment: I see  -dunno about django. postgres allows, eg `create table a()` will create table with no columns

Comment: Hey, @M.AhsenTaqi I was wondering, did you found my answer helpful?

Answer (score 2):

What you want is to create `Dynamic Models`. There is a very detailed wiki article about that:

1. [Django Dynamic Models](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/DynamicModels) which explains step by step how to achieve a dynamic model. A quick sample from that article:

   Implement a function able to build a model on demand:

   ```
   def create_model(name, fields=None, app_label='', module='', options=None, admin_opts=None):
       """
       Create specified model
       """
       class Meta:
           # Using type('Meta', ...) gives a dictproxy error during model creation
           pass

       if app_label:
           # app_label must be set using the Meta inner class
           setattr(Meta, 'app_label', app_label)

       # Update Meta with any options that were provided
       if options is not None:
           for key, value in options.iteritems():
               setattr(Meta, key, value)

       # Set up a dictionary to simulate declarations within a class
       attrs = {'__module__': module, 'Meta': Meta}

       # Add in any fields that were provided
       if fields:
           attrs.update(fields)

       # Create the class, which automatically triggers ModelBase processing
       model = type(name, (models.Model,), attrs)

       # Create an Admin class if admin options were provided
       if admin_opts is not None:
           class Admin(admin.ModelAdmin):
               pass
           for key, value in admin_opts:
               setattr(Admin, key, value)
           admin.site.register(model, Admin)

       return model
   ```

   Now you can parse your CSV file and decide about your fields and then create your model:

   ```
   import csv

   def csv_to_model(path_to_csv):
       with open(path_to_csv, "rb") as f:
           reader = csv.reader(f)
           col_names = next(reader)

       fields = {}
       for name in col_names:
           fields[name] =  models.CharField()

       return create_model(fields)
   ```

   Of course, you can make more complicated models. Read the [wiki](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/DynamicModels) for a more thorough explanation.
2. There exist this django package: [django-dynamic-model](https://github.com/dobarkod/django-dynamic-model) which claims to add dynamic model creation on django (*I cannot confirm that works*):

   ```
   from dynamicmodel.models import DynamicModel, DynamicSchema, DynamicForm

    def csv_to_model(path_to_csv):
       with open(path_to_csv, "rb") as f:
           reader = csv.reader(f)
           col_names = next(reader)

       schema = DynamicSchema.get_for_model(MyModel)
       for name in col_names:
           schema.add_field(name=name, type='CharField')

       return schema
   ```